# Eclipse freezes and eventually crashes while opening class

Tags: eclipse

I'm developing a java project. Unfortunately, eclipse (version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)Build id: 20150219-0600) decided to crash when I was working on a specific java class.

Symptoms: when opening the class for editing, CPU ramps up to 100%. When left for about 5 minutes, eclipse crashes with "An internal error occurred during: "Compacting resource model". GC overhead exceeded."

Without this specific class file, the project works fine. It's a relatively small project (<50 files), so nothing out of the ordinary there. When I open the file in a separate project (without all its dependencies) it works fine as well). My eclipse ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```

The .metadata/.log file:

```
====================== .log:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-04-18 09:58:08.350
!MESSAGE Error setting focus to : org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartImpl GraphManipulator.java
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.getVisible(Control.java:2958)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1441)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1441)
        at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.setFocus(StatusTextEditor.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.setFocus(JavaEditor.java:2389)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.delegateSetFocus(CompatibilityPart.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.focusGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:795)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$2.setFocus(ContributedPartRenderer.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem.setFocus(CTabItem.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setFocus(CTabFolder.java:2555)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.fixFocus(Control.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setVisible(Control.java:4871)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3098)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3055)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1259)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4590)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1262)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1215)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.closePart(StackRenderer.java:1218)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.access$3(StackRenderer.java:1200)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$12.close(StackRenderer.java:1092)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1874)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-04-18 09:58:09.371
!MESSAGE Error setting focus to : org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartImpl ColGen.java
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.getVisible(Control.java:2958)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1441)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1441)
        at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.setFocus(StatusTextEditor.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.setFocus(JavaEditor.java:2389)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.delegateSetFocus(CompatibilityPart.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.focusGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:795)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$2.setFocus(ContributedPartRenderer.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem.setFocus(CTabItem.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setFocus(CTabFolder.java:2555)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.fixFocus(Control.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setVisible(Control.java:4871)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3098)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3055)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1259)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4590)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1262)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1215)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.closePart(StackRenderer.java:1218)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.access$3(StackRenderer.java:1200)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$12.close(StackRenderer.java:1092)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1874)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)


!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-04-18 10:57:19.080
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Compacting resource model".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.HashMap$EntrySet.iterator(HashMap.java:1005)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:180)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.toArray(Collections.java:2027)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.utils.StringPoolJob.run(StringPoolJob.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-04-18 10:57:19.081
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-04-18 10:57:19.081
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-04-18 10:57:19.082
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Decoration Calculation".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

The file causing the problem: [BranchAndPrice.java](https://github.com/jkinable/jorlib/blob/development/jorlib-core/src/main/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/branchAndPrice/BranchAndPrice.java)

Some of the commonly mentioned steps I tried:

- moving org.eclipse.core.resources, restarting eclipse, moving the files back
- starting a new fresh project

Comment: Plenty of memory related exceptions in the log. Have you tried increasing the -Xmx value in the eclipse.ini?

Comment: yes, I increased in to 4G. As a result, eclipse doesn't respond anymore, and my computer pretty much hangs.

Comment: I've created a bug report for eclipse which includes 2 JVM dumps: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=464928